# Move data to flatfile only if lookup returns rows

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to move data from multiple csv files to a DB destination.For doing this I'm using a For Each Loop container that contains a Data Flow Task for shifting the data file-wise which consists of a merge join and a lookup transformation, the end result being that records with a match are inserted to the DB and non-matching records are transferred to a CSV destination.

The lookup transformation is used to lookup data in the file with pre-existing data in the DB and forward the No Match Output to a csv destination.

This works fine with files that have some non-matching data. However, with files wherein all data matches,I'm still getting an empty No-match file.I would like to avoid creating an empty file. I've tried using a conditional split based on the condition `LEN(Column_Name) > 1` to work around but that doesn't work.

Would appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little more work, but a work around I might suggest is to use the row count transformation in the no-match path. Then add a file system task at the end of your package and delete the CSV file if the row count equals 0.

Comment: Tried that already Mike. I was looking for a logic wherein the empty file doesn't get created in the first place. Ended up dumping all data in a temp table and then sending it to files year-wise.